# vb.net dropdownlistfor from an enum

Tags: vb.net

Hi I need to do a dropdown list for to an enum.

For recover my enum, in my viewmodel I do like this :

```
Public Property datatype As New List(Of DataTypeNameEnum)    
Dim values() As Integer = CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(DataTypeNameEnum)), Integer())
For Each value In values
    datatype.Add(value)
Next
```

And in my view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.datattypeAsEnum, New SelectList(Model.datatype, "name", "name"))
```

But I have an error:

```
name doesn't exist in DataTypeNameEnum
```

How I can to do for take values of my enum, and recover them in my selectList ?

edit : solved, i add attribute in jquery to my option.

Answer (score 0):

I can recover my list if i add a property "testname"
and in my constructor :

```
Sub New(adt As AttributeDataType)
    Me.testname = adt.Name
    datatype.Add(testname)
End Sub
```

I have my dropdownlist, but my options have only the name like this :

```
<option>Name</option>
```

Value is not here...why ? 
I take all the arguments in my dropdownlistfor :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.datattypeAsEnum, New SelectList(Model.datatype,Model.testname, Model.testname))
```